# Windows 8 Store App Live Tile Image Position

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I have a live tile in my Windows 8 store app which is defined as TileWideImageAndText01 and TileSquarePeekImageAndText04. The image is in an format which doesn't fit the tile, so I guess the tile is taking the center of the picture?

Actually I want the tile to take the top of my picture and not centering it.

Is it possible to change this behaviour in my live tile declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I found out that there is no out-of-the-box-solution for my problem.

I solved it by creating a BitmapResource out of my image, cropping it programmatically and save it back to my ApplicationFolder, where I can reference the image in my live tile with "ms-appdata:///...."